# How to obtain summary summation when GROUP BY is not working?

Tags: sql, sas

I have data with the columns

- User_id (char)
- filename (char)
- filesize (numeric)

Every user_id has more than 5 files to it's name, of different filesize values.

**Problem statement:** I want to have a summary of this table, with columns, *User_id, Filesize*, where it shows the total size occupied by each user id.

It tried Group By user id, in Proc SQL,

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE want as 
SELECT user_id, filesize 
FROM have
GROUP BY user_id;
QUIT;
```

but it throws a warning that says

> A GROUP BY clause has transformed into an ORDER BY clause because neither the SELECT clause nor the optional HAVING clause of the associated table-expression referenced a summary function.

Are there other ways to do this in SAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE want as 
SELECT user_id, SUM(filesize) as TotalFileSize 
FROM have
GROUP BY user_id;
QUIT;
```

Comment: worked like a charm. i have a basic working knowledge of sas by now, but proc sql gets out of my comfort zone everytime. Could you suggest what's the best resource to learn sql online?

Comment: https://www.sas.com/store/books/categories/examples/proc-sql-by-example-using-sql-within-sas-/prodBK_60500_en.html